# Error in getting functions worked

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In **demo_api_controller.rb** I have function like `"post '/fetch_specialities'"`.
Here I am calling following functions which are present in `"lib/facts.rb"`

```
1) rel_date = get_rel_date('MED')
2) rel_date = get_zipcode_by_state('NY')
3) rel_date = get_specs('MED')
```

From these, #1 is working properly and displaying latest release date. #2 & #3 are not working.

Getting the following error:

```
 NoMethodError at /demo_api/fetch_specialities undefined method `get_zipcode_by_state' for #<DemoApiApp:0x4e686b1f>
```

Comment: Your action is `post` yet you're calling `get_...`

Comment: Please post the contents of `lib/facts.rb` - or at least the parts where you define `get_zipcode_by_state` and `get_specs`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a `get_zipcode_by_state` method available in the scope you're in. Doublecheck that you actually have that method available and haven't made a typo.

Potentially you need to restart your server process to pick up the changes in `lib`.

Comment: Is this an answer? It looks like *prose* for the error message.

Comment: How can I restart the service? I'm a noob here.

Comment: That depends on how you've started it, but during development it's likely hitting CTRL+C in the terminal window where you started your Sinatra app, and then starting it again.

Comment: I restarted httpd on linux, but it still shows the same error.